# How to embed translate.google.com without iframe/object (X-Frame-Options is SAMEORIGIN)

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, google-translate

I am trying to embed the [google translator page](http://translate.google.com/). I would like to have the same behaviour as the google translator website has, two boxes, and 'arrow' to change the languages, etc.

I have tried with an *iframe* or with HTML5 *object* tag, but google has the *X-FRAME-OPTIONS="SAMEORIGIN"* so it is forbidden to frame anything and the new browsers don't show it.

Another option would be to use [google gadgets](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open), but I have read that they are going to be deprecated and the [google translate gadget](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&hl=es&url=http://www.deptmit.webs.com/GoogleTranslateGadget2.xml) doesn't have the same features as the web has.

The last option is to use the [google translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/), but it is a paid service. 
Besides I am not going to send thousands texts to translate and saturate google, the users devices will access to google servers and translate something if they want, so I doesn't has sense to paid for it.

Do you have any idea what can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could always opt for something like what I put on the [Organique](http://www.organiquehomespa.com) page.

It's a JavaScript widget that's similar to Google translate -- you just put it on each page.

```
<!-- GTranslate: http://gtranslate.net/ -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#goog-gt-tt {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-banner-frame {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-menu-value:hover {text-decoration:none !important;}
.goog-te-gadget-icon {background-image:url(http://joomla-gtranslate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gt_logo_19x19.gif) !important;background-position:0 0 !important;}
body {top:0 !important;}
-->
</style>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,autoDisplay: false, includedLanguages: ''}, 'google_translate_element');}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I dont want to translate my page, I want to have two _textarea_ [like translate.google.com has](http://i.imgur.com/w62ArED.png) and give to the user the option to translate texts. With iframe tag it would be very simple :-)
Thanks again

Comment: okey doke, misunderstood obviously, i'll leave the answer there - it might be helpful to someone.